# UITextField has different background on TestFlight and mac output

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, testflight

Recently I deploy my app on TestFlight for inner test.
I found UITextFields on my app has different background colors on TestFlight and directly output by my mac.

Is it just a TestFlight bug? Or an iOS version difference?

[image: attached 1: directly output by my mac.]

attached 1: directly output by my mac. User: iOS 14.4.2

[image]

attached 2: on TestFlight. Users: iOS 14.4, iOS 14.5.1

I've checked the code. Nothing is different. At least I didn't find difference.

Comment: Try turning off dark mode in your phone and then test on TestFlight. If that fixes it, dark mode is the issue

Comment: oops, the black square is I added for erase. It's black and white for attach 1, but clear for attached 2.

Answer (score 0):

Dark mode might be the issue. Try manually setting up background color to debug.

Comment: I think not. Attach 1 is black and white, but attached 2 which from TestFlight is clear. This is not a black mode issue.

Comment: Ok, you might mean I should custom the background color. It might solve problem. Thanks.

Comment: yes. that's what I meant. Give custom color